# How to get access token from FBSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook SDK in order to get user groups in an application
but I am getting a null access token.
My code in `viewDidLoad` is as follows.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:appID permissions:@[@"basic_info",@"user_groups",@"email"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone urlSchemeSuffix:nil tokenCacheStrategy:nil];

[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info",@"user_groups",@"email"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error in Session Opening %@",error.description);
        NSLog(@"access Token %@",session.accessTokenData.accessToken);
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/groups" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"%@",result);
            }else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error %@",error.description);
            }


        }];


}];
}
```

**OUTPUT of this code is :-**

```
Error in Session Opening (null)
access Token (null)
Error Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x1090acc80 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 2500;
            message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}}
```

As you can see the access token is null..

What am I doing wrong ?

Is there something extra which should be added in this code ?

Thanks

Comment: Look at the error object in your outer completion handler. Clearly, opening the session failed for some reason and so you do not have an access token.

Comment: @Niraj : did it already, its null

Comment: Sorry, can you try to look at any other properties in the error such as status code, domain etc.

Comment: Sorry, can you try to look at any other properties in the error such as status code, domain etc. Also, is there a reason why you are creating the session yourself? if you specify your app id in your info.plist as described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/), you can get rid of the initWithAppID line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the correct facebook appID? Why not specify nil, i.e.,

```
self.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:nil permissions:@[@"basic_info",@"user_groups",@"email"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone urlSchemeSuffix:nil tokenCacheStrategy:nil];
```

That'd be one less place to go wrong. As it says in [FBSession class reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/)

> If nil is passed in the default App ID will be obtained from a call to
>   <[FBSession defaultAppID]>. The default is nil.

Also, you don't have to alloc/init the FBSession yourself, but if you want to, you should follow the 3-step process specified in [FBSession lifecycle](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/#sessions), including checking for `FBSessionStateCreated` before proceeding with one of the `open` methods, as quoted from [FBSession lifecycle](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/#sessions):

> Instead of calling one of the static openActiveSession* methods, your app can achieve the same flow following these steps:
>
> 1. Call one of the FBSession instance init functions.
> 2. Check if the state value has transitioned to FBSessionStateCreated.
> 3. If the state value is FBSessionStateCreated, call one of the
>      FBSession instance
>          open functions.

Answer (score 1):

you want this:

```
session.accessTokenData.accessToken
```

where 'session' is your FBSession

which you can get from...

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
{
// If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"]
               allowLoginUI:NO
                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,     FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
        {
          NSLog(@"%@", session.accessTokenData.accessToken);
        }];
    }
```